# Is Odin four gods rolled into one?

Tags: marvel, thor-marvel, odin

In *Thor* #294 it shows that Odin is the fusion of four elder gods of an earlier Asgard. In later issues it says that he is Bor's son. Which is it?

Comment: Per the [Marvel wiki](http://marvel.com/universe/Odin#ixzz4T7GkFnp4): "*Odin claimed his father was dead and assume rule over his lands alongside his brothers Vili and Ve. The three brothers returned to their father's kingdom of Asgard, which had become home of the gods. **Upon the apparent death's of his brothers at the hands of the fire-demon Surtur, Odin absorbed their life essences,** increasing his own power (the "Odinpower").*

Comment: In the Norse / Finnish eddas Odin and his brothers are sons of Bor.

Comment: He's four smaller gods in a trench coat!

Answer (score 4):

It does seem to be a matter of "Reader's Choice".

As Buri remarks in "Thor" #355, "...I know which I should believe."  For myself, I know I will **definitely** go with the story that hews closer to the traditional Norse myths than the "Eyeball Story".  Thor, son of Odin, son of Bor, son of Buri.

[image: Buri talks to Thor about Odin]

Comment: If you can't trust a floating eyeball, who can you trust?